# Selenium webdriver-Jenkins Email notification

Tags: email, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, email-ext

I am not getting mails on project success when using Jenkins, Please tell me the stable plugins for
jenkins & email-ext plugin. Now, I am getting email only when test fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to add a trigger for success emails. By default, only the failure trigger is added to the email-ext project configuration. You need to expand the "Advanced" section and add a success trigger as well.